# What is $x$ in the following question?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

Here is the question:

$$ \frac 23 \div x = \frac 12 + \frac 13 .$$

I would be very grateful if someone could find the value of $x$.

Thank You.

Comment: $${{2/3}\over x}={1\over 2}+{1\over3}\iff {{2/3}\over x}={5\over 6}
\iff {x\over {2/3}}={6\over 5} \iff x={6\over5}\cdot{2\over3}={4\over 5}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} = \frac{3+2}{6} = \frac{5}{6}.$$
So what you have is equivalent to
$$\frac{2}{3}\div x = \frac{5}{6}.$$
Note that $x$ cannot be zero. Multiplying both sides by $x$, we get
$$\frac{2}{3} = \frac{5}{6}x.$$
Can you solve it now?

Comment: Yes Thank you very much! The answer is 4/5!